# Irregulations with Google Analytics Organic Search Sources

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, reporting

Please help me to understand where is the problem with my Organic Search Sources in my Google Analytics reports (OSS).
Couple of months ago I've checked my referral traffic for new search engines and updated my OSS.
E.g., one of updates:
     Search Engine Name: yahoo
     Domain name: us.search.yahoo.com
     Query parameter: p
     Path: *empty field*

Now i'm checking my last month data report (Acquisition > All traffic > Source/Medium):
     position #5: yahoo / organic
     position #19: us.search.yahoo.com / referral ( [censored]?)

In my understanding, all the traffic from #19 (due to my OSS) should be simply added to #5.
Worst case scenario, I should have got: us.search.yahoo.com / organic, not referral...

What am I missing here?